# Why didn't iPhone data completely carry over during iPhone upgrade at an Apple Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup, migration

I recently upgraded from an **iPhone 12** to an **iPhone 13** at an Apple Store.

Some apps migrated properly, some apps didn't.

I migrated the data with Migration Assistant while connected to the store's wifi for at least an hour as seen in this image.

[image]

After I wiped clean and returned the **iPhone 12** (this was a trade-in situation, so I didn't take the iPhone 12 home), I noticed that the **iPhone 13** did not carry a lot of app-specific data - both Apple apps that were supposedly **iCloud** backed (all my **Safari** tabs disappeared) and non-Apple apps (for example **Polycam 3D LIDAR capture**, which doesn't have an iCloud backup option in *Settings*).

**If I decide to upgrade to an iPhone 14 in the future while trading in my 13, what can I do to make sure the migration of all my data happens without any data loss?**